# Jira trigger plugin for Jenkins doesn't work

Tags: jenkins, jira-plugin

I'm trying to use [JIRA Trigger](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jira-trigger/#documentation) Jenkins plugin. I've read maybe all similar issues but can't understand why it doesn't work.

I want to build when an issue status changed. I troubleshooted but it didn't help me. My web hook works I checked it as it shows in documentation, the plugin for Jenkins is installed,  firewall checked (I have whitelisted 3 Jira cloud IPs for Jenkins instance on AWS), `ssl` checks on Jenkins passes. Also I configured logs on Jenkins from Jira, but can't get anything.

In trigger configuration I inserted my Jira user's email (my-email@gmail.com) as user and password. The user has administrator privileges. What else can be wrong? Please any idea.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your question is not well asked, as it is confusing what are you trying to achieve and what you have done and what are the exact errors you got. Some log with the error may be helpful (or a statement that you don't get any log). Not sure you've also noticed, but your plugin is looking for help with maintenance (may not be actively maintained): `This plugin is up for adoption.`

Comment: Did you check and follow the steps at [jira-trigger-plugin – Troubleshooting – Build is not triggered](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jira-trigger-plugin#troubleshooting)?